# Can someone explain me what is the difference between union All and join in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, join, oracle11g, union-all

I am searching for this question since last 2 days what is the difference between UNION and JOIN. Specifically UNION ALL and Natural JOIN.
So I have 2 queries here 
first one is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VU_m1 AS 
SELECT department_id,manager_id FROM employees 
NATURAL JOIN departments ;
SELECT * FROM vu_m1;
```

and the second one is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VU_m2 AS 
SELECT department_id,manager_id FROM employees 
UNION ALL
SELECT department_id,manager_id FROM departments; 
SELECT * FROM vu_m2;
```

The result from both the query is exactly same.
So now what is the difference between UNION ALL and Natural JOIN

Details:
I am using Oracle 11gR2 working on Sample HR database.

Comment: a union All takes two sets of data and combines them into one list with all the results keeping duplicates.  Thus the row count is equal to the sum of both sets.  A Join (inner in the example as it's optional) will only includes results where both sets match, and have separate columns for each of the columns in each set.  The row count is equal to only those values which match on the natural join between both tables. (natural join = columns with same name)

Answer (score 3):

This is my 2 cents

```
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
+- UNION                           +- JOIN                                      +
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
+SELECT 1 AS bah FROM DUAL         + SELECT *                                   +
+      EMP.DEPTNO                  + FROM                                       +
+SELECT 2 AS bah FROM DUAL;        + (SELECT 1 AS bah from dual)  foo           +
+                                  + JOIN                                       +
+                                  + (SELECT 2 AS bah from dual)  bar           +
+                                  + ON 1=1;                                    +
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
+-                              RESULTS                                         +
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
+This gives everything in vertical + This gives everything in horizontal        +
+    BAH                           + BAH  BAH                                   +
+    1                             + 1    2                                     +
+    2                             +                                            +
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
+-                             OBSERVATIONS                                     +
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
+ UNION puts lines from queries    + JOIN makes a Cartesian product             +
+ after each other                 + and subsets it                             +
+                                  +                                            +
+ UNION combines the results of    + JOIN can retrieve data from two or         +
+ two or more queries into a single+ more tables based on logical relationships +
+ result set that includes all the + between the tables. Joins indicate how SQL +
+ rows that belong to all queries  + should use data from one table to select   +
+ in the union.                    + the rows in another table.                 +
+                                  +                                            +
+ UNION makes two queries look     + JOIN examine two or more tables in         +
+ like one.                        + a single query statement                   +
+                                  +                                            +
+ UNION returns the results of two + JOIN relates similar data in different     +
+ different queries as a single    + tables.                                    +
+ recordset.                       +                                            +
+                                  +                                            +
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

**JOIN** picks fields from table A and fields from table B and put all of them together, JOIN is "horizontal" for example:

```
SELECT A.A1, A.A2, A.A3, B.B1, B.B2
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.A10 = B.B20
```

which can be written also like:

```
select A1, A2, A3, B1, B2 from TABLEA, TABLEB
WHERE A10 = B20
```

result:

```
Field-A1 | Field-A2 | Field-A3 | Field-B1 | Field-B2 |  
...
```

**UNION/UNIONALL**:

Difference between the two is that UNION returns only distinct results while UNIONALL returns ALL the results (including duplicates). UNION/UNIONALL combines the results of two selects - but there's a "catch" - the column-names must be exactly the same - this property make UNION "vertical", for example:

```
Select A1 as X1, A2 as X2 from TABLEA
UNIONALL
Select B1 as X1, B2 as X2 from TABLEB
```

result:

```
Field-X1 | Field-X2
A1      | A2
B1      | B2
...
```

Comment: Good answer, Though I don't think field names don't need to be the same, just the number of them and the data type.

Comment: @xQbert maybe I should rephrase: you can select fields with different names and give them the same "nickname" for example: `select A1 as TMPNAME from Table`

Comment: If you don't alias the second select columns you will still get X1 and X2 in the results right? (So is name important?) (I only quibble on this point becuase of the satment column-names must be EXACTLY the same, I don't think that is a true statement) However,if A1 is varchar and B1 is date regardless if they are named the same the union will fail right?  So is the name important or should emphasis be on the number of columns and their data types?   Still a good answer, just think emphasis doesn't belong on the name. (unless you're talking about the natural join...)

Answer (score 1):

join:
A join is an SQL operation performed to establish a connection between two or more database tables based on matching columns, thereby creating a relationship between the tables. Most complex queries in an SQL database management system involve join commands. 
e.g:
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order
syntax:
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;